# Adding BERT embeddings in LSTM embedding layer

Tags: deep-learning, keras, word-embedding, long-short-term-memory, bert

I am planning to use BERT embeddings in the LSTM embedding layer instead of the usual Word2vec/Glove Embeddings. What are the possible ways to do that?

Comment: do you want the entire bert contextual embedding or just the subword embeddings?

Comment: I would need the contextual embeddings.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `Embedding()` layer directly, you can create a new `bertEmbedding()` layer and use it instead.

```
# Sample code
# Model architecture

# Custom BERT layer
bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=10)(bert_inputs)

# Build the rest of the classifier 
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(bert_output)
pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(...)
```

This [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-in-keras-with-tensorflow-hub-76bcbc9417b) will walk you through the entire process of creating the custom BERT layer along with example code. Give it a read.